# Compilation failure [ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

Tags: maven, selenium, pom.xml

I have set the environment variables properly, still im getting the below error in the console, when im trying to run clean install command in Maven build.

[image]

Comment: Are you setting below property in maven build file  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

Comment: The setting of `<maven.compiler.source..>..` will not help if the outside JDK/JRE is not correctly configured.